# Serial Communication on the UART Pins in raspberry PI3

Tags: raspbian, raspbian-jessie

iam Beginner to PI3 
iam facing one problem in the Raspberry Pi3

currently i want to do serial Communication on the UART pin 14 and 15,
where i have done loopback,
Problem i faced is iam not able to send any data

Task done
As Raspberrypi3 ttyAMA0 is assigned to bluetooth , so iam using the ttyS0
,where iam using gtkterminal for configuring the port and send the data

by help of website help , i changed the config.txt
  by including the Enable_uart=1,core_freq=250
and even though non of the data is flowing

so kindly any one can help me to solve this problem

Comment: Could you post a photo of the loopback over 14/15?  Pins 14/15 are not the UART.  Pins 8/10 are the UART,  Do you mean GPIO 14/15?  A photo will remove ambiguity.

Comment: Have you enabled serial? See [How-do-i-make-serial-work-on-the-raspberry-pi3](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/45571/8697) NOTE it is `enable_uart=1` check if `/dev/serial0` exists

Answer (score 1):

if you're not using Bluetooth you can disable it or switch the ports by adding `pi3-miniuart-bt` or `pi3-disable-bt`. check `/boot/overlays/README` and run this `systemctl disable hciuart`. I just disabled Bluetooth on mine and got back "ttyAMA0" everything working as it should.

On another note i think you don't need to set `core_freq` if you use `enable_uart=1`.

Comment: yes , i have disabled the bluetooth under the config.txt , done the enable_uart=1 successfully, and ran the systemctl disable hicuart , even though iam not able to see any data on the screen , the port is getting opened successfully , iam using gtkterminal to perform the operation

Comment: @Rangith123, check the baudrate maybe ...

Comment: @Rangith123, also, you can use piscope tool for see the datas modulation on  RX and TX pins in software side.